# Is creating an environment necessary in Anaconda python?

Tags: python, anaconda, environment

Creating a new environment often requires re-installations of python compiler and spyder ide, over again. This consumes both internet data as well as disk space in the computer. So is this really necessary? Why can't we do all the coding in the default "base" environment that we get after anaconda is installed? If I am working on ten different research projects of different themes, do I need to create ten different python environments?

Comment: The purpose of different evironment is to make sure libraries don't get conflicted with each other. So you don't need to create one for each project. I usually just create one when something wrong when a new library is installed

Comment: @YukiShioriii Thank you for the reply. But aren't all libraries unique? How can a conflict arise? Are there multiple versions of the same libraries installed?

Comment: Usually library also use other libraries ( called dependencies ) in their own too, so dependency libraries can be updated while the one using didn't, thus creating conflict @Vikash.

For example [this](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/requirements.txt) is pytorch dependencies, and if numpy update deprecate something it might lead to some problems.

Comment: @YukiShioriii Thank you for the explanation. Appreciated. So how often should I create new environment? This seems confusing to me.